# Unable to Set and Get the values in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use setter and getter. When i debug, the value gets set but when i try to retrieve, it gets null value.

Class1.cs

```
private string setMAX;
        public string SETMax
        {
            get
            {
                return setMAX;
            }
            set
            {
                setMAX = value;
            }
        }

private string value1;
        public string MaxValue
        {
            get
            {
                return value1;
            }
            set
            {
                value1= value;
            }
        }
```

Class2.cs

```
Class1.SETMax = Class1.value1; //This gets set
```

Class3.cs
//When i debug, first Class1.cs and Class2.cs completes, then it comes in Class3.cs

```
string max = Class1.SETMax; //I GET NULL here.
```

I dont know where I am wrong here.Can anyone please explain me ?

Comment: Please provide reasonably complete sample and detailed error message. I.e. there is absolutely no way to know what `File1` stands for - class name, local variable name, field name,...

Comment: Also you never show how value is expected to *not be set to `null`*...

Comment: I'm guessing you have different _instances_.  Show how you're setting the values and when/how you're evaluating them,

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov its a class, i edited the it

Comment: You are not instantiating the objects. Try `Class1 class1 = new Class1();` before you set or access any values.

Comment: Also, use auto-properties ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `File1` as an instance.  You are probably referencing different instances.  You probably want static properties.

```
    private static string setMAX;
    public static string SETMax
    {
        get
        {
            return setMAX;
        }
        set
        {
            setMAX = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few things mixed up so lets start from the beginning

```
Class1.SETMax = Class1.value1; 
// for a start you are assigning a 
// private variable to a public one 
// via the Class definition I'm not even sure how that compiles.
```

Have a look here see if this makes sense to you

```
// This is a Class definition
public class Class1 {
 public string SETMax {get; set;}
 public int MaxValue {get; set;}
}


// This is your application
public class MyApp{

 // this is a private field where you will assign an instance of Class1
 private Class1 class1Instance ;

 public MyApp(){
   //assign the instance in the constructor
        class1Instance = new Class1();
 }

 public void Run {
  // now for some fun

   class1Instance.SETMax = "Hello";
   Console.WriteLine(class1Instance.SETMax); // outputs "Hello"
   var localInstance = new Class1();
   localInstance.SETMax = class1Instance.SETMax;
   Console.WriteLine(localInstance.SETMax); // outputs "Hello"

}
 }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with assigning a value to a private field in a public setter.  In fact, it is the usual pattern.

Comment: @phoog this is what I was talking about.  Class1.SETMax = Class1.value1; it's just plain wrong

Comment: Peter is right, he tried to access private field of Class1 in Class2. That is not possible!!

Comment: @WeryNguyen, Peter: I see, I overlooked the fact that the line in question is in Class2.cs.